# Why i am gething different h3 index with same latitude and longitude

Tags: python, c, h3

I am working with a SQlite hexagon index database and other information, the Hexagons index is the primary key. This database is generated by code written in python, and other codes written in C use the hexagonal index to access the information stored in the database.

```
for res_hex in [12,11,10,9,8]:
            index_hex = h3.geo_to_h3(sonde[1], sonde[0], res_hex)
```

sonde[1] is latitude, sonde[0] is longitude res_hex is the resolution.

In fact, I have a list of objects represented by their latitude and longitude in a text file, I calculate the indexes around them with different resolutions (8 to 12). that I enter the database.

But my problem is that when I calculate the hexagon in code c with lat, lon and the resolution, I do not find it in the base. This even if the calculation is based on the same file.

```
GeoCoord geo = {latitude, longitude};
H3Index currentIndex = geoToH3(&geo, resolution);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I also want to know which between the mode 1 and mode 2 indexes is return by the k-ring function.

Comment: What do you mean by "mode 1" and "mode 2"? If you mean the mode bit of the index, the k-ring function always returns cells (`H3_HEXAGON_MODE`), not edges.

Comment: in fact, I wanted the hex to have the neighboring hex in a given direction.

Comment: The k-ring function does not guarantee order within a ring, if that answers your question

Comment: is there some way to order them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find a solution, in C Lat/Lon must be in radians but it is not the case in python

Comment: That's correct - in C, the input is in radians, but in the various bindings the input generally is lat/long instead.